# Is there such thing as a heat / power management?

Tags: 11.10, power-management

I was having a [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70977/dell-vostro-3550-and-ubuntu-1x-xx-dual-display) with my screen resolution constantly changing on the fly while X was running with dual monitors.

Actually i am still having this problem but i think i figured out what was the trigger. 
It seems to happen only when my laptop starts to heat up when doing some CPU intensive tasks.

So i am wondering if there is such thing as a program that run in the background that tries to regulate heat or maybe the power management, that i could disable in order to get rid of the problem mentioned above. Maybe the unity equivalent of the gnome settings manager..

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Program doesn't run in the background, but Jupiter Power management can scale your CPU, which should cool it down when it's too hot, hope this helps, it runs as a panel applet.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

if by chance you have an EEEPC (i doubt that) sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee

Comment: Thanks Jman though i might not have explain my self clearly but i am looking for a native program that would try to scale the CPU or GPU, so that i can desactivate it.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for jupiter and install powertop from [here](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/)